# Javascript not functioning when clicking the back button

Tags: javascript

I have this code in place

```
let showAboutSection = () => {
  if(userInfo.logged && userInfo.subscriber && !userInfo.in_trial) {
  let section = document.querySelector('.cbt-tabs')
   if(section) {
    if(!section.classList.contains('touched')) {
    section.style.display = 'block'
    section.classList.add('touched')
    return
  }
}
}
setTimeout(showAboutSection, 500)
}

showAboutSection()
```

But if you click on the back button or on one of my navigation tabs without refreshing the screen, it does not function. Please help!

Comment: Have you checked if userInfo values checked in the first line inside showAboutSection are true + section is found by the querySelector? Seems like that's the issue here.

Comment: Yes, the values are true and the section is being found by the selector. The reason I know this is because the function does work but when I click the back button the the browser then go back to the page where the function should fire, it does not work.